# Change Padding on Borderless Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, button, padding

I am developing an application, but I have run into a slight issue. I am a huge fan of the Borderless Button style (`style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"`), but I cannot change the padding on the buttons. Why do I need to change the padding? Because there is a minimum padding or width of the buttons that can make them look unpleasant, or just make waste space. This issue can be seen when there is very little text:

[image]
[image]

The capped spacing is there one where the minimum width of the button is 'capped'.
I have tried setting the padding to zero programmatically and messing with the padding in XML but nothing works.
I have noticed that the `AlertDialog` does not have this issue as bad:

[image]
[image]

You can see in the background the 'Capped' Spacing card compared to the Dialog. My question is, how can I reduce the padding myself? I would prefer not to have to write a custom style for the button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to apply the `AlertDialog` button style to your button:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
```

For a more detailed answer, the space around the text here isn't exactly padding as such. The minimum size is determined by other attributes set in the style which is why trying to tweak the padding doesn't work, padding only starts to have an effect on bigger buttons(ie. longer text).

If we dip into the styles, it reveals a potentially useful technique to help. The `AlertDialog` button style looks like this:

```
<!-- Alert dialog button bar button -->
<style name="Widget.Material.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog" 
    parent="Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored">
    <item name="minWidth">64dp</item>
    <item name="minHeight">@dimen/alert_dialog_button_bar_height</item>
</style>
```

So the `AlertDialog` button actually inherits from the `Borderless.Colored` style and only tweaks a couple of attributes: `minWidth` and `minHeight`.

You could also do this, either by making your own style similar to the one above, or by setting `minWidth` and/or `minHeight` directly on the button.

```
<Button
    ....
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:minHeight=... />
```

Playing around with these will hopefully get the result you're looking for, and if you go as far as setting the `minWidth` and `minHeight` to 0dp, then it becomes all about the content and the padding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This solution is better than none, but I am still hoping that there is a way to make the padding even less.

Comment: @Pythogen I've expanded the answer, hopefully more helpful.